# Akka ask() timeout does not work

Tags: java, akka

I am making two calls to different agents by executing following code.

```
 Timeout t = new Timeout(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

 Future<Object> eventFuture = ask(this.customerEventActor, new GetCustomerEventActionsMessage(customerCookie), t);
 Future<Object> infoFuture = ask(this.customerPersonalInfoActor, new GetCustomerPersonalInfoMessage(customerCookie), t);
```

Inside my actor I am pausing a thread for 1000 ms and returning results back. I expect it will fail timeout error. But then I look at results status comes as successful and has a valid response. `EVENTS! Time taken: 4931` So it took 4931 ms to execute and it didn't timeout. Why?

```
public class CustomerEventActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        CustomerEventResponseMessage msg = new CustomerEventResponseMessage();
        msg.events = "EVENTS! Time taken: " +  (System.currentTimeMillis() - now);
        getSender().tell(msg, getSelf());
        getContext().stop(getSelf());
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that there is no additional messages in logs? "EVENTS! Time taken: " should be printed either way (timeout doesn't stop the actor itself, only future). All timeout do is failing your `eventFuture` and printing some message to the current logger

Comment: @dk14, I can understand that timeout does not stop an actor itself - thats fine, but why eventFuture is not failed?

Comment: how do you check the future? could you please add your `eventFuture.onSuccess(...)` code to the question

Comment: @dk14, Well... I haven't finished that bit yet, I just stop it with a break point and see response status, it tells me that it is successful. Is it not a good think to do?

Comment: I don't know on what field you're actually looking for (there is no isSuccessful field), because `isCompleted` for instance should be true, as future will be *completed* with AskTimeoutException after timeout. I would recommend you either to write some test-code or at least publish screenshot from debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a future fails it does not throw an exception.

A future is completed in two possible ways:
1) Success(result) - you can then get the result from the future
2) Failure(failure) - you can get the failure parameter which is usually an exception (the AskTimeoutException in your case)

You never actually look at the completed future, so you have no way of knowing if it succeeded or not.